# mailchimp trigger API automation for 'already subscribed'

Tags: mailchimp

we use Mailchimp automation. For new clients that fill out our form this works fine - we send them a welcome e-mail and an offer.

The problem now occurs here: we have noticed that about 12-20% of already subscribed customers don't realize they are subscribed ---- and subscribe again!

However there is no API event that marks this event to our knowledge. We would ate least like to 'inform' the 'already subscribed' that they are already subscribed - or give them a small extra. But don't let it end in a dead track (no response at all).

So ideally we would like to

- (possible) new customers: send welcome and offer
- (not possible?) already subscribed: inform them + give small extra

**my question is:** how can we specifically target already subscribed customers that subscribe a second time (and exclude new subscribers) coming from the API through automation in Mailchimp?

Has anyone done something like this before? We use the Hellobar btw. We don't want people who fill out a form: to hear nothing from us.

UPDATE:
As suggested by @TooMuchPete maybe through and API error. But there is no link to an 'error' trigger

[Example op API 3.0 set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THY3u.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second Automation that is API triggered. Then, when your API subscribe call results in a 'user already subscribed' error, you could add them to that automation.

Comment: thanks for that. Sounds interesting. I was browsing though all settings, but cannot find this one. Is it under API 3.0 call - I don't see any options to capture the 'error' .... under whcih automation workflow can I find it in Mailchimp? really appreciate you help

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You make the subscribe request. If the API [returns an error](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/api-3-overview), have your code [trigger an Automation email](https://blog.mailchimp.com/new-automation-workflows-and-api-functionality/). It's not automatic, you'll have to take that action yourself.

Comment: Aha. We use hellobar(.com) thats subscribes customers. So I was hoping to 'detect' events in Mailchimp. I have no control over the external app making the API call.

Comment: Sounds like something to take up with hellobar -- or you could do something like setting a merge field/interest group and trigger the automation on that.

Comment: thanks for that. Yes a merge field would have been great only currently you need to hard set it (i.e. new merge field value will be 'XXXX'); to date there is no trigger for merge field "has changed"..... which would be great. Also I understand that the API 'touches' the record and changes the last updated field: that would be the most ideal event to latch on to I guess .... reported it to Mailchimp - might help if other do that too. http://mailchimp.com/contact/feedback/

Answer (score 0):

This is not scientific reasoning, but trying to handle the error doesn't feel like the right approach.

Also, changing a merge field, which triggers a workflow, is a very patchy way to work around it (which I've also done many times before), but the problem is that you can only do it once. If a subscriber subscribes again in 2-3 months, nothing will happen, and we effectively have the same problem.

Another way would be to check if [date added] is lower than [last changed], which indicates that they're already subscribed.

Fortunately, with Mailchimp API v3.0 we can trigger a workflow for a subscriber, hopefully as many times as we want.

This is what you need:
[Add a subscriber to a workflow](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/automations/emails/queue/) with Mailchimp API v3.0

And if you're new to API v3.0, this is a great basic guide showing [how to manage subscribers](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/).

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore. If you try to send same email a second time with API V3, you get this error : `[title] => Bad Request [status] => 400 [detail] => You’ve already sent this email to the subscriber.`

Comment: just run into this issue as well. Did you find a workaround how to send the same email twice by triggering the automated workflow?